# Cloudfront can't connect to custom origin ALB showing 502 error

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

Created CloudFront Distribution with all the necessary config and with the valid SSL cert.
Set Origin Domain as load balancer DNS name.
Set CNAME as

abc.fleethawks.com (abc - subdomain name can't disclose)

Set Viewer Policy as Match Viewer

Redirect HTTP to HTTPS.

[Cache Key & Origin Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIraw.png)

After successfully created.
When i tried to access through distribution, it shows 502.

[502 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fem6w.png)

When i tried access through CNAME as configured above, it works but when i geo restrict India, it should not work .
But In my case it still works even after geo restriction.

Comment: What is the actually issue? 502 error or that geo restrict does not work? Sadly your question is unclear.

Comment: I am getting 502 error when through cf distribution domain. So i thought it's because i configured CNAME while configuring cloudfront, so that's the issue. To confirm this, i geo restricted and paste CNAME in browser and hit enter, then it worked. But how can it possible if i geo restrict my country, it shouldn't work